# How to insert multiple dataframes into excel file from python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have dataframe in which file number column has unique 5 values, i created a program in which two different dataframes are formed as result for that file number. For e.g. for file number 55 output are df1,df2, for file number 56 output are df1,df2 and so on. I want to save this results in a single excel file containing sheet names 55,56,57 etc in which sheet names contains output that file number i.e. df1 & df2. I want to automate the process of saving the output in excel file, I don't want to mention file number.
I tried,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')  
workbook=writer.book
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('55')
writer.sheets['55'] = worksheet
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='55',startrow=0 , startcol=0)  
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='55',startrow=15, startcol=0)
writer.save()
```

Here I need to mention 55 manually, it should take from `df['File Number'].unique()`
Any guess how to make excel sheet containing all the output for file numbers?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for fn in df['File Number'].unique():
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{fn}', startrow=0, startcol=0)  
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{fn}', startrow=15, startcol=0)
```